Crashlytics not sending reports from Android emulator crash?
I've setup Crashlytics for my React Native Expo app following this guide and configure and test following this guide.
Crash reports from Android Emulator are never sent to the console, while from iOS simulator crashes are successfully sent. For some reason the logs constantly show various random Google services crashing.
In Firebase console, Craslytics tab just says "App detected, waiting for a crash".
This is part of the output from adb logcat | grep -i crash where it shows an intended crash caused by crashlytics().crash();, and than app being restarted:
--------- beginning of crash
05-07 23:32:06.474  6708  8510 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crash Test
05-07 23:32:06.474  6708  8510 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule$1.run(ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule.java:83)
05-07 23:32:06.486  6708  8510 E DevLauncher: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crash Test
05-07 23:32:06.486  6708  8510 E DevLauncher:   at io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule$1.run(ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule.java:83)
05-07 23:32:07.064   505   825 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.keepalive.StandaloneKeepAlive$KeepAliveService in 1000ms for start-requested
05-07 23:32:07.217   505   540 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.dialer/com.android.voicemail.impl.scheduling.TaskSchedulerJobService in 10847ms for connection
05-07 23:32:09.007   505   825 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.google.android.inputmethod.latin/com.android.inputmethod.latin.LatinIME in 1000ms for connection
05-07 23:32:09.014   505  4145 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.scheduler.process.mainimpl.PhoneskyJobServiceMain in 10993ms for connection
05-07 23:32:09.014   505  4145 W ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service com.android.vending/com.google.android.finsky.setup.PlaySetupServiceV2 in 20993ms for connection
05-07 23:32:09.049  9648  9691 V DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils
05-07 23:32:11.826 10538 10601 I org.webrtc.Logging: CrashStartupListener: Checking conference crashes for 0 account(s).
05-07 23:32:11.891 10538 10619 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
05-07 23:32:11.926 10538 10619 I FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrashApiImpl created by ClassLoader dalvik.system.DelegateLastClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~9F99x1_jvOfwerB_h9KckQ==/com.google.android.gms-4eYR5-JR7gmCVw1wXDy6qw==/split_DynamiteModulesC.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~9F99x1_jvOfwerB_h9KckQ==/com.google.android.gms-4eYR5-JR7gmCVw1wXDy6qw==/split_DynamiteModulesC.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]]
05-07 23:32:11.930 10538 10620 W DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.crash not found.
05-07 23:32:11.942 10538 10620 I FirebaseCrashApiImpl: FirebaseCrash reporting API initialized
05-07 23:32:11.943 10538 10620 W FirebaseCrashAnalytics: Unable to log event, missing Google Analytics for Firebase library
05-07 23:32:19.148 10538 10893 I FirebaseCrash: Sending crashes
05-07 23:32:30.993 10835 11164 V DynamiteModule: Dynamite loader version >= 2, using loadModule2NoCrashUtils

and this is another log:
User
--------- beginning of crash
05-07 22:29:41.560  5607  5830 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crash Test
05-07 22:29:41.560  5607  5830 E AndroidRuntime:    at io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule$1.run(ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule.java:83)
05-07 22:29:41.564  5607  5830 E DevLauncher: java.lang.RuntimeException: Crash Test
05-07 22:29:41.564  5607  5830 E DevLauncher:   at io.invertase.firebase.crashlytics.ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule$1.run(ReactNativeFirebaseCrashlyticsModule.java:83)
05-07 22:30:13.877  5928  5928 D SessionsDependencies: Dependency to CRASHLYTICS added.
05-07 22:30:13.940  5928  5928 I FirebaseCrashlytics: Initializing Firebase Crashlytics 18.6.4 for japodium.android
05-07 22:30:13.969  5928  5928 D SessionsDependencies: Subscriber CRASHLYTICS registered.
05-07 22:30:14.026  5928  5928 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled via RNFBJSON: true
05-07 22:30:14.026  5928  5928 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled after checking crashlytics_debug_enabled: true
05-07 22:30:14.027  5928  5928 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled final value: true
05-07 22:30:14.027  5928  5928 I RNFBCrashlyticsInit: initialization successful
05-07 22:30:14.110  5928  5961 D libcrashlytics: Initializing libcrashlytics version 3.2.0
05-07 22:30:14.135  5928  5961 D libcrashlytics: Initializing native crash handling successful.
05-07 22:30:14.178  5928  5961 I FirebaseCrashlytics: No version control information found
05-07 22:30:14.527  5928  5928 I flipper : flipper: FlipperClient::addPlugin CrashReporter
05-07 22:30:14.759  5928  5970 D SessionConfigFetcher: Fetched settings: {"settings_version":3,"cache_duration":170183,"features":{"collect_logged_exceptions":true,"collect_reports":true,"collect_analytics":false,"prompt_enabled":false,"push_enabled":false,"firebase_crashlytics_enabled":false,"collect_anrs":true,"collect_metric_kit":false,"collect_build_ids":true},"app":{"status":"activated","update_required":false,"report_upload_variant":2,"native_report_upload_variant":2},"fabric":{"org_id":"663a70a7fe68bd5be8e001c8","bundle_id":"japodium.android"},"on_demand_upload_rate_per_minute":10,"on_demand_backoff_base":1.2,"on_demand_backoff_step_duration_seconds":60,"app_quality":{"sessions_enabled":true,"sampling_rate":1,"session_timeout_seconds":1800}}
05-07 22:30:14.877  5928  5948 D SessionLifecycleClient: Notified CRASHLYTICS of new session 59d616f9a2c14337af406f0a2737dd80
05-07 22:30:14.896  5928  5948 D EventGDTLogger: Session Event: {"eventType":1,"sessionData":{"sessionId":"59d616f9a2c14337af406f0a2737dd80","firstSessionId":"59d616f9a2c14337af406f0a2737dd80","sessionIndex":0,"eventTimestampUs":1715113814871000,"dataCollectionStatus":{"performance":1,"crashlytics":2,"sessionSamplingRate":1.0},"firebaseInstallationId":"cK__aUjFRmSjU8mOmowwQB","firebaseAuthenticationToken":"eyJhbGciOiJFUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhcHBJZCI6IjE6ODg1ODY2MjQ4MjgxOmFuZHJvaWQ6NGQwM2IxNzk5OGFkYTQwZWYxNTk0OCIsImV4cCI6MTcxNTcxODUwMCwiZmlkIjoiY0tfX2FVakZSbVNqVThtT21vd3dRQiIsInByb2plY3ROdW1iZXIiOjg4NTg2NjI0ODI4MX0.AB2LPV8wRAIgD5t9Jco3cfZqF9rWr_5r8vAmzKqpXBpv9llfxZHHEGwCIDv9lAyux6rJm4DXZxikHC-ZadZ-zVoOQd8aTcOIckWr"},"applicationInfo":{"appId":"1:885866248281:android:4d03b17998ada40ef15948","deviceModel":"sdk_gphone64_arm64","sessionSdkVersion":"1.2.4","osVersion":"14","logEnvironment":3,"androidAppInfo":{"packageName":"japodium.android","versionName":"1.0.0","appBuildVersion":"1","deviceManufacturer":"Google","currentProcessDetails":{"processName":"japodium.android","pid":5928,"importance":100,"defaultProcess":true},"appProcessDetails":[{"processName":"japodium.android","pid":5928,"importance":100,"defaultProcess":true}]}}}
05-07 22:30:16.644  5928  5928 I flipper : flipper: FlipperClient::removePlugin CrashReporter
05-07 22:30:17.857  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled via RNFBJSON: true
05-07 22:30:17.857  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled after checking crashlytics_debug_enabled: true
05-07 22:30:17.857  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled final value: true
05-07 22:30:17.857  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isErrorGenerationOnJSCrashEnabled via RNFBJSON: true
05-07 22:30:17.857  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isErrorGenerationOnJSCrashEnabled final value: true
05-07 22:30:17.858  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsJavascriptExceptionHandlerChainingEnabled via RNFBJSON: true
05-07 22:30:17.858  5928  6044 D RNFBCrashlyticsInit: isCrashlyticsJavascriptExceptionHandlerChainingEnabled final value: true

